# Use "dotnet" or ".NETPlatform5.0" in NuGet nuspec?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core, nuspec

I have a NuGet .nuspec created with with various framework dependencies.

Based on [this](https://oren.codes/2015/07/29/targeting-net-core/) article, one of the dependencies is "dotnet":

```
<group targetFramework="dotnet">
[dependencies here]
</group>
```

When I pack the .nuspec file using NuGet 3.3, the nuspec file that gets packed up has "dotnet" replaced by ".NETPlatform5.0":

```
<group targetFramework=".NETPlatform5.0">
[dependencies here]
</group>
```

What's the impact here, if any?

Should I use "dotnet" or ".NETPlatform5.0" going forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured this out myself by reading the docs at [NuGet](https://docs.nuget.org/create/targetframeworks#supported-frameworks) and [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms)

NuGet looks at the "dotnet" moniker and finds the best platform to use, in my case "dotnet5.0", which is actually .NETPlatform5.0.

Confusing as hell, but that's RC life I guess :)